# "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs" exception when trying to reserve ID

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am currently moving the database from my former GAE application to a new one.
I have a home made backup/restore mechanism that has been working for years in my previous application. 
For some reasons I have some relationship between entities that are serialized (I am using @Serialize from Objectify), that's why I need a custom backup/restore.

Thus I would like to keep the current auto-generated ID in the new model. To do so, and to avoid collision I tried to use the DatastoreService allocateIdRange.
For every IDs from my database, I get the "Exceeded maximum allocated IDs" exception. Even for the recently created entities.

The solution I found in the other similar thread was not to use this API, and to migrate to a custom auto-generated ID (using UUID.randomUUID()).

If I have no other choices, this will be my solution as well, however, I can't see any reason why allocateIdRange is not working for my case.

For your informations, the IDs I am try to allocate are around that size :
4925503928532992

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I came with an idea during the night that could work! There is a way to restore the database from another application using the app engine backup/restore functionality.

The idea is to first restore a backup from another application (that should reserve the IDs), and then to restore the exact same backup using my mechanism to update the entities.

EDIT: As it is explained in this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring#backup_and_restore_considerations, this solution should be working properly. I guess this is a good workaround, even if the allocateIdRange should be working.